# Sp 2010 - indexed record returned in one query not in another

Tags: 2010, index, advanced-search

I have a very large Sharepoint document archive, about 15 million PDFs. The records are indexed, but I'm seeing two issues, one of which I'll prioritize here.

In one library (only about 5K records) records will return when I query specific dates for two custom columns (Run date, to pick one), but the returned list will not return all records if I request a date range. They do return sometimes, so clearly they're indexed, but I'm at a loss why the range would fail.  And there's no pattern - there's two report documents a day; some days' reports, both return, some days only one of them will return, some days none.  And it's consistent - the same reports for any day continue to not return, so it doesn't seem to be a random thing.

Now I have a second issue where is I try to do a very large query (many thousand results) I won't get all results, as in it only seems to return a certain number and then gives up, only returning what it can carry. But the queries I'm making here should only return 15 - 20 records, and as I say, the library is rather small, so I don't believe that issue is playing a role, but who knows.

I could try a re-index, but since the index for the site is so large, it'll take many hours, possibly over a day, and I'd rather exhaust my other options to make the current data behave.

Any thoughts?